# Dynamically create a QML object of a type

Tags: qt, qml

`Qt.createComponent(...)` only accepts a URL to a custom component, but how can I create a component of, say, `Item` type?

I want something like `Qt.createComponent(Item)` or `Qt.createComponent("Item")`, but these don't work. I don't really need a component because I want to get an object as the result, so maybe there is something like `Item.createObject(...)`?

Comment: Can you explain your use case? Would a `Loader` meet your needs instead?

Comment: @JarMan , I need to dynamically create and add multiple elements, the same way it's described [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-javascript-dynamicobjectcreation.html) but instead of a custom component (declared in a .qml file), I need to use an existing qml type (Image in the example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a component statically, and create objects from it dynamically. Is this what you're looking for?

```
Component {
    id: itemComp
    Item {}
}

Component.onCompleted:  {
    var item1 = itemComp.createObject(parentObj)
    var item2 = itemComp.createObject(parentObj)
    ... // etc...
}
```